# What tag wiki am I editing?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I'm churning through some suggested edits, and see a tag-wiki edit which, while reasonably informative, doesn't conform to our newly agreed upon standards, so I hit Improve. Here's what I see:

[image: Improve Suggested Edit]

Wait, what tag was this again?

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The new review design now includes the tag that you're editing when you hit 'Improve':

[image: New Review queue design for suggested edits]